# JUnit: testing exception on java reflect

Tags: java, exception, reflection, junit

I have a class `MyTransformFunctions` that has reflect method (name : transform) like this:

```
public class MyTransformFunctions
{

Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger( MyTransformFunctions.class );

public MyRecord transform( String functionName, MyRecord argRecord, String argFieldToProcess )
        throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException,Exception
{

    try
    {
        Method method = this.getClass().getDeclaredMethod( functionName, argRecord.getClass(), argFieldToProcess.getClass() );
        argRecord = (MyRecord) method.invoke( this, argRecord, argFieldToProcess );

    }
    catch ( NoSuchMethodException e )
    {
        LOG.error( "[ Method not found exception] : Method name '" + functionName + "'" + " field name: '" + argFieldToProcess
                + "' " + e );
        throw e;
    }
    catch ( java.lang.IllegalAccessException e )
    {
        LOG.error( "[ Illegal Access exception] : Method name '" + functionName + "'" + " field name: '" + argFieldToProcess
                + "' " + e );
        throw e;
    }
    catch ( java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException e )
    {
        LOG.error( e.getCause().getMessage() + "[ Invocation Target not found exception] : Method name '" + functionName + "'"
                + " field name: '"
                + argFieldToProcess
                + "' " + e );
        throw e;
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        LOG.error( e.getCause().getMessage() + "[ Transformer function exception ] : Method name '" + functionName + "'"
                + " field name: '"
                + argFieldToProcess
                + "' " + e );
        throw e;
    }


    return argRecord;

}

public MyFuction( MyRecord record, String fieldNameToProcess )
{
    LOG.debug( "convert2GoogleDate function called" );
    return record;
}
}
```

I am trying to write junit test to check individual exception is thrown from the transform method and getting compilation error. My test looks like:

```
@Test(expected = NoSuchMethodException.class)
public void testFailedGetMethod() throws NoSuchMethodException
{
    MyRecord record = new MyRecord();
    transformer.transform( "junk", record, "junk" );

}
```

I am getting "unhandled exception" during compilation.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `transform` method throws more than just `NoSuchMethodException`.  It also throws `IllegalAccessException`, `InvocationTargetException`, and `Exception`.

This compilation error has nothing to do with JUnit and everything to do with the fact that those exceptions declared to be thrown by `transform` aren't caught by your testing method.  Because `Exception` is the superclass of all thrown exceptions here, you can quick-fix this by declaring your test method to throw `Exception`.

```
public void testFailedGetMethod() throws Exception
```

That will get it to compile.  However, just throwing an `Exception` is not good practice.  It's better to use a specific subclass of `Exception`, and sometimes that can lead you to create your own subclass of `Exception` to represent this exceptional condition, e.g.

```
public void testFailedGetMethod() throws NoSuchMethodException,
    IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, SomeOtherException
```